# Where is the flutter plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed flutter plugin in my Android Studio,

[image]

but in my macOS Terminal, I can't use `flutter` by default, so I want to set the softlink of it.

but I didn't find the flutter directory,

```
ls /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
CodeResources   MacOS       _CodeSignature  jre     license
Info.plist  Resources   bin     lib     plugins
```

I also list the `bin` and `plugins`, I didn't find the flutter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flutter plugin in Android Studio is just a plugin for helping you to develop Flutter apps, it does not include Flutter SDK with it.

Please check out this official tutorial to download Flutter SDK and combine it with Android Studio: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Later to access `flutter` command in Terminal, you can add flutter `bin` folder path to `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`.